# Referencing cell in the same row as cell found with MAX formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of statistics pulled from the FBI website.

I want to find the MAX in a column, so i wrote this: `=MAX(F6:F561)`

Now i want to divide that max value into a value from the same row but in a different column. How would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use match to search for the max value and index to get the value from the other column:

```
=MAX(F6:F561)/INDEX(G6:G561,MATCH(MAX(F6:F561),F6:F561,0))
```

Or use the Index Match combo in any other way you need.